# It is off-topic now, but it wasn't then, so do I vote to close?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

I have recently (after reaching 3k and unlocking the ability to cast close and reopen votes) noticed that a lot of questions that were not off-topic when they were originally asked are being flagged up now. So really my question is, if for instance somebody has asked a question about Ubuntu 13.10, and they asked it when it was the current release, do I vote to close it now as it still does not have an accepted answer and it is now an End Of Life release?

Now I have noticed a difference of opinions about this, and am now not really too sure whether to vote to close or not, so I was hoping for some moderator and community feedback on what is the best thing to do in these circumstances. It would also be rather good if this subject could be officially agreed on and for there to be some sort of guide that explains what you should do in these circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So really my question is, if for instance somebody has asked a question about Ubuntu 13.10, and they asked it when it was the current release, do I vote to close it now as it still does not have an accepted answer and it is now an End Of Life release?

In general you leave it as it is.

There are some actions to consider:

- If someone eventually does answer it with a correct answer: fine and leave it as is. Upvote if good enough.
- If the question seems to be not release specific remove the release specific information from the question. That can be assessed from both the question and if it ends up having an answer from the answer.
- If someone answers it with wrong information you flag that answer.